# Append Slice to Struct in Golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to append an array to another array (or slice to struct?) 
The result from a query (target) is iterated and appended with result from another query (target per checkpoint) based on previous query result.id

Then the result is iterated in a template.

### Model

```
type Target struct {
    ID              uint32        `db:"id"`
    CriteriaID      string        `db:"criteria_id"`
    TargetCheck     []*TargetCheck
}

type TargetCheck struct {
    ID              uint32        `db:"id"` 
    TargetID        string        `db:"target_id"`
    CheckpointID    template.HTML `db:"checkpoint_id"`
    Name            string        `db:"name"`
}

func TargetByCriteriaID(criteriaID string) ([]Target, error) {
... <return rows> 
}

func CheckpointByTargetID(targetID uint32) ([]TargetCheck, error) {
... <return rows>
}

func (target *Target) AddItem(TargetCheckItem *TargetCheck) []*TargetCheck {
    target.TargetCheck = append(target.TargetCheck, TargetCheckItem)
    return target.TargetCheck
}
```

### Controller

```
func CriteriaBrowseGET(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

criteriaID := 5
target, err := model.TargetByCriteriaID(criteriaID)
for i := range target {
        targetCheck, err := model.CheckpointByTargetID(target[i].ID)
        target = model.Target.AddItem(targetCheck)
    }

v := view.New(r)
v.Name = "criteria/browse"
v.Vars["target"] = target
v.Render(w)

}
```

### View

```
{{range $index, $content := .target}}
    <p>Target: {{.ID}}</p>
                    {{if .}}
                        {{range .TargetCheck}}
                            <p>{{.CheckpointID}}</p>
                            <p>{{.Name}}</p>
                        {{end}}
                    {{end}}

{{end}}
```

### When performing `go build` it says:

> vendor\app\controller\criteria.go:74:24: invalid method expression
>   model.Target.AddItem (needs pointer receiver: (*model.Target).AddItem)
>
> vendor\app\controller\criteria.go:74:24: model.Target.AddItem
>   undefined (type model.Target has no method AddItem)

Is there any problem with the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error clearly indicates:

> vendor\app\controller\criteria.go:74:24: invalid method expression
>   model.Target.AddItem (needs pointer receiver: (*model.Target).AddItem)
>
> vendor\app\controller\criteria.go:74:24: model.Target.AddItem
>   undefined (type model.Target has no method AddItem)

that you have pointer receiver to method `AddItem` here:

```
func (target *Target) AddItem(TargetCheckItem *TargetCheck) []*TargetCheck {
    target.TargetCheck = append(target.TargetCheck, TargetCheckItem)
    return target.TargetCheck
}
```

But when you are calling the function from controller your are using value receiver:

```
    targetCheck, err := model.CheckpointByTargetID(target[i].ID)
    target = model.Target.AddItem(targetCheck)
```

You should pass pointer receiver when calling the function `AddItem`.

[Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/v7H-xQBmccQ)

It is described in Golang spec for [Method Declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations):

> The receiver is specified via an extra parameter section preceding the
>   method name. That parameter section must declare a single non-variadic
>   parameter, the receiver. Its type must be of the form T or *T
>   (possibly using parentheses) where T is a type name. The type denoted
>   by T is called the receiver base type; it must not be a pointer or
>   interface type and it must be defined in the same package as the
>   method. The method is said to be bound to the base type and the method
>   name is visible only within selectors for type T or *T.
>
> Given type Point, the declarations:

func (p *Point) Length() float64 {
        return math.Sqrt(p.x * p.x + p.y * p.y)
    }

```
func (p *Point) Scale(factor float64) {
    p.x *= factor
    p.y *= factor
}
```

> bind the methods Length and Scale, with receiver type *Point, to the
>   base type Point.

Answer (score 1):

`target = model.Target.AddItem(targetCheck)` is wrong, you should be calling a method on the `target` value that you have obtained from the `range` statement so do `&target.AddItem(targetCheck)` instead